# The event can be triggered after change the frame of superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uistoryboard

```
1.Show a popup when tap a button(KLCPopup)

2.Change the height of contentView(KLCpopup) when tap the 'change frame' button,and change the height successfully

3. Tap  'change frame' button again, I want change the height again, but it does not work.
```

the source is in https://github.com/leogeng/LabProject.git

Who can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can fix it but it is best you do it. Let this answer be a bit more about how to debug your application.

After a very short analysis I put a breakpoint in your button action method and found out it is only called once. So it does not resize the second time because the button is not working at all.

What the candidates for that are is the button is being tempered with in ways such as interactions disabled, it is over-layed with another view which prevents the touch events, or its superviews are not correctly sized to detect touches.

After using the view debugger (there is an icon you may use in runtime which displays the view hierarchy) I can see the black button on the blue background which is on some transparent background whose size is too small and the blue view is out of bounds.

It seems you need to resize the superview of the blue view as well.